Prettier setting to preserve space for prettier table formatting
I made a table

  const transitions: any = [
        /* fromState        event         toState         callback */
        t(States.zombie, Events.click,    States.walk,    ()=>animation("walk")),
        t(States.walk,   Events.click,    States.jog,     ()=>animation("jog")),
        t(States.jog,    Events.off,      States.off,     onClose),

but prettier keep truncating spaces which would be normal but unreadable at first glance:

  const transitions: any = [
        /* fromState        event         toState         callback */
        t(States.zombie, Events.click, States.walk, ()=>animation("walk")),
        t(States.walk, Events.click, States.jog, ()=>animation("jog")),
        t(States.jog, Events.off, States.off, onClose),

How to instruct prettier to keep spaces/ formatting?

Prettier has // prettier-ignore comment to stop uglifying line below it.
More details can be read in prettier documentation.
